# Disaster recovery for RAID and mdadm

Tags: partitioning, gparted, gpt, mdadm, partition-recovery

I´m having a software raid 5 with 5 2TB members. After some work with gparted my RAID doesn´t work any more... How can I check the integrity of each member?

What would be my options, if the partition tables of the members were broken?

greetings Nico

Comment: Can you be more specific than 'doesn't work any more'?  What exactly doesn't work? Are the drives down? Does the system still boot? Is raid 5 disabled in some way?

Comment: No, my Fedora told me, that it couldn´t find any mdx devices. My disks are working, but not the software raid.